# Como pegar os parâmetros de uma Url no Android

Tags: java, android, url

No [android](/questions/tagged/android) tenho a seguinte `URL`

```
String url = "http://domain.com/page?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2";
```

Gostaria de pegar os parâmetros desta `URL` como faço isso de uma forma simples?

Answer (score 3):

Para fazer isso você pode utilizar a classe `URLEncodedUtils` que é uma classe utilitária do [android](/questions/tagged/android) para `URL`'s

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
String url = "http://domain.com/page?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2";
 List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url),"utf-8");
for (NameValuePair p : parameters) {
    System.out.println(p.getName());
    System.out.println(p.getValue());
}
```